# Add files to subfolders using rest api in javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts

What is working right now is i can upload to the root folder of a library using the code below :

```
 myDropzone.options.url = `${_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/Lists/getById('${_parent.props.listName}')/rootfolder/files/add(overwrite=true,url='${file.name}')`;
```

What i want is to be able to send the files to a specific folder. i have tried using the below code but i get 404 error.

```
 myDropzone.options.url = `${_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/Lists/getById('${_parent.props.listName}')/folders/folder1/files/add(overwrite=true,url='${file.name}')`;   




myDropzone.options.url = `${_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/Lists/getById('${_parent.props.listName}')/rootfolder/folders/folder1/files/add(overwrite=true,url='${file.name}')`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested below endpoint in fiddler, it works fine.

Correct your endpoint as folders('folder1').

```
/sites/Developer/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyDoc4')/RootFolder/folders('SubFolder')/files/add(url='test.txt',overwrite=true)
```

Comment: am still getting the error 400 

`${_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/Lists/getById('${_parent.props.listName}')/rootfolder/folders('folder1')files/add(overwrite=true,url='${file.name}')`;

Comment: i missed a '/' before files. it works

Comment: but if i have something like this folders('folder1/folder2'), it doesn't work

Comment: Use /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyDoc4')/RootFolder/folders('SubFolder')/folders('F')/files/add()

Comment: i am getting the path dynamically,is there any other solution where i can just inject "folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/..." . The code above is a static way if you know the exact subfolder numbers

Comment: You may change to /_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/Developer/MyDoc4/subfolder/f')/files/add(), or split the path and join as /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyDoc4')/RootFolder/folders('SubFolder')/folders('F')/files/add()

Comment: i can't figure why i get 403 error :
testtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(/sites/test/test1/folder1/folder11)"

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl() like this

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/test folder1/folder inside test folder/folder3')/files/add(url='test.txt',overwrite=true)
```